# Does Google provide support for Google APIs for vaadin if not using google app engine as a runtime..?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, vaadin, vaadin7

I am new in vaadin and developing a web project so want to know if i do't use **Google App Engine** as my project's run time environment so that  am able to use Google all APIs such as:

```
*Calender API
*Contact API
*Drive API
* and also other which google provide :
```

[Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/)

As i get to know that **GAE** has lot of limitations.
Please suggest me for the structure design of an Enterprise project with 
**Maven+vaadin+Runtime Environment(Jboss)+Eclipse+MySQL**

Comment: I think you must split this into two things: Google specific things -> ANswered/supported by Google. Vaadin things -> Supported by Vaadin

Comment: I just want to go for vaadin with google APIs so i need the answer to start my project otherwise it will dependent over GAE.

Comment: I don't think google api is restricted to GAE (of course the GAE part, but not the other services)

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs does not require your application to be running on Google App Engine unless of course you’re trying to use an App Engine specific API like [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api).

If you’re seeking suggestions on how to structure your project using Google App Engine, you may want to do so in official App Engine [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) as such questions can be considered too broad on stackoverflow.

Comment: @ssh Please look into my problem

Comment: but i think its important to deploy at google server (GAE) for use google API @zeehad-a